# Mocking os.path.exists and os.makedirs returning AssertionError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, python-mock

I have a function like below.

```
# in retrieve_data.py

import os

def create_output_csv_file_path_and_name(output_folder='outputs') -> str:
    """
    Creates an output folder in the project root if it doesn't already exist.
    Then returns the path and name of the output CSV file, which will be used
    to write the data.
    """
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)
        logging.info(f"New folder created for output file: " f"{output_folder}")

    return os.path.join(output_folder, 'results.csv')
```

I also created a unit test file like below.

```
# in test_retrieve_data.py

class OutputCSVFilePathAndNameCreationTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('path.to.retrieve_data.os.path.exists')
    @patch('path.to.retrieve_data.os.makedirs')
    def test_create_output_csv_file_path_and_name_calls_exists_and_makedirs_once_when_output_folder_is_not_created_yet(
            self,
            os_path_exists_mock,
            os_makedirs_mock
    ):
        os_path_exists_mock.return_value = False
        retrieve_cradle_profile_details.create_output_csv_file_path_and_name()
        os_path_exists_mock.assert_called_once()
        os_makedirs_mock.assert_called_once()
```

But when I run the above unit test, I get the following error.

```
def assert_called_once(self):
    """assert that the mock was called only once.
    """
    if not self.call_count == 1:
        msg = ("Expected '%s' to have been called once. Called %s times.%s"
               % (self._mock_name or 'mock',
                  self.call_count,
                  self._calls_repr()))
         raise AssertionError(msg)
         AssertionError: Expected 'makedirs' to have been called once. Called 0 times.
```

I tried poking around with `pdb.set_trace()` in `create_output_csv_file_path_and_name` method and I'm sure it is receiving a mocked object for `os.path.exists()`, but the code never go pasts that `os.path.exists(output_folder)` check (`output_folder` was already created in the program folder but I do not use it for unit testing purpose and want to keep it alone). What could I possibly be doing wrong here to mock `os.path.exists()` and `os.makedirs()`? Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: Not a direct answer to your problem, but have you considered using [pyfakefs](https://pypi.org/project/pyfakefs/)?  It mocks the whole filesystem, so you don't need to focus your tests on the implementation, but rather test the behavior and the end results.

Comment: @flakes Thank you for the suggestion. I am writing code for a corporation and it doesn't allow me to integrate/use unapproved packages (meaning, the available Python packages are limited).

Comment: I'd suggest looking into getting approval, we have similar restrictions but it usually just requires talking to someone. If not I would probably write your own fixture utilizing [TemporaryDirectory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory) instead of mocking all of the os calls. That will lead to more flexible tests resistant to having changes in implementation breaking them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the arguments to your test function reversed. When you have stacked decorators, like:

```
@patch("retrieve_data.os.path.exists")
@patch("retrieve_data.os.makedirs")
def test_create_output_csv_file_path_...():
```

They apply bottom to top, so you need to write:

```
@patch("retrieve_data.os.path.exists")
@patch("retrieve_data.os.makedirs")
def test_create_output_csv_file_path_and_name_calls_exists_and_makedirs_once_when_output_folder_is_not_created_yet(
    self, os_makedirs_mock, os_path_exists_mock
):
```

With this change, if I have this in `retrieve_data.py`:

```
import os
import logging

def create_output_csv_file_path_and_name(output_folder='outputs') -> str:
    """
    Creates an output folder in the project root if it doesn't already exist.
    Then returns the path and name of the output CSV file, which will be used
    to write the data.
    """
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)
        logging.info(f"New folder created for output file: " f"{output_folder}")

    return os.path.join(output_folder, 'results.csv')
```

And this is `test_retrieve_data.py`:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

import retrieve_data


class OutputCSVFilePathAndNameCreationTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("retrieve_data.os.path.exists")
    @patch("retrieve_data.os.makedirs")
    def test_create_output_csv_file_path_and_name_calls_exists_and_makedirs_once_when_output_folder_is_not_created_yet(
        self, os_makedirs_mock, os_path_exists_mock
    ):
        os_path_exists_mock.return_value = False
        retrieve_data.create_output_csv_file_path_and_name()

        os_path_exists_mock.assert_called_once()
        os_makedirs_mock.assert_called_once()
```

Then the tests run successfully:

```
$ python -m unittest -v
test_create_output_csv_file_path_and_name_calls_exists_and_makedirs_once_when_output_folder_is_not_created_yet (test_retrieve_data.OutputCSVFilePathAndNameCreationTest.test_create_output_csv_file_path_and_name_calls_exists_and_makedirs_once_when_output_folder_is_not_created_yet) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

---

**Update** I wanted to leave a comment on the diagnostics I performed here, because I didn't initially spot the reversed arguments, either, but the problem became immediately apparent when I added a `breakpoint()` the beginning of the test and printed out the values of the mocks:

```
(Pdb) p os_path_exists_mock
<MagicMock name='makedirs' id='140113966613456'>
(Pdb) p os_makedirs_mock
<MagicMock name='exists' id='140113966621072'>
```

The fact that the names were swapped made the underlying problem easy to spot.

Comment: That is it! I can't believe I struggled for more than an hour because I didn't know that `@patch` is applied in reverse order.  Thank you so much!